# Google App Engine Java Mail: Always send mail to self

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance( props, null );
        Message msg = new MimeMessage( session );
        msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( from ) );
        msg.addRecipients( Message.RecipientType.BCC, adds.toArray( new InternetAddress[]{} ) );
        msg.setSubject( subject );
        msg.setText( msgbody );
        Transport.send( msg );
```

For example current login user(from) is A, he sends mail to B(recipient), then both A and B will receive A's email, that's annoying, any ideas? I'm sure the recipients do not contain self(A).

Comment: what is adds.toArray contain? did you read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail ? how if you try to hardcode it?

Comment: Yes i read the doc, and the recipient do not contain sender's mail.